# Alachisoft.NCache.Web.SessionState.NSessionStoreProvider can't find protobuf-net

Tags: asp.net

I've downloaded the open source edition of ncache and i've followed the instructions at http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/help/aspnet-session-state-provider.html?mw=Mzk2&st=MQ==&sct=MTk4&ms=QwAAEAAAIAAAAQACATgIAhA=

to configure my website to put the session state in ncache.

However,  i get this error hitting the site.

Configuration Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'protobuf-net, Version=1.0.0.282, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

Line 136:    
Line 137:

Source File:  C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxxx\web.config    Line:  138

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'protobuf-net, Version=1.0.0.282, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67' could not be loaded

I'm not sure where to find that dll or why it can't be loaded?   I tried using nuget to install protobuf-net but there is no 1.0.0 version and the recent version does not fix the problem when i copy it to the bin folder.

Randy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that you need NCache installed on the web servers too, in addition to the cache servers.   This is a better page to follow if you are just starting out with NCache for sessionState.

http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/ncache-session-guide.pdf